# Mongoexport -q ISODate query

Tags: mongodb, isodate

I'm trying to run this:

```
mongoexport.exe -h *MYHOST* -p *MYPORT* -q "{'time':{'$gte': ISODate('2014-12-21 12:57:00.506Z'),'$lt': ISODate('2014-12-21 12:59:00.506Z')}}"
```

Or this(the gte & lt without - ' ):

```
mongoexport.exe -h *MYHOST* -p *MYPORT* -q {'time':{$gte: ISODate('2014-12-21 12:57:00.506Z'),$lt: ISODate('2014-12-21 12:59:00.506Z')}}
```

The query works fine on Robomongo, But with mongoexport it throws: "too many positional arguments"

I know I can run the following instead, But I don't want to use the date converter everytime I need to execute a query.

```
mongoexport.exe -h *MYHOST* -p *MYPORT* -q "{'time':{$gte: new Date(14191
66620506),$lt: new Date(1419166740506)}}"
```

Comment: Duplicate of this newer question, [Use mongoexport with a --query for ISODate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36319052/use-mongoexport-with-a-query-for-isodate), which has better answers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

mongoexport queries require the use of strict-mode MongoDB extended JSON. You can read more about that flavor of extended JSON in the MongoDB Manual article on [extended JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/). In your specific case, the proper way to write the first query in the mongoexport command is

```
mongoexport.exe -h *MYHOST* -p *MYPORT* -q "{ 'time' : { '$gte' : { '$date' : '2014-12-21 12:57:00.506Z' },'$lt' : { '$date' : '2014-12-21 12:59:00.506Z' } } }"
```

Comment: Is this answer still valid? Querying by string instead of ISODate seems not to return any results whereas adding ISODate("") constructor will return results - in the mongo shell directly. In mongoexports, adding ISODate("") (or JS Date object) constructor causes an error.

Comment: It appears that this will work properly, but the timestamp can be very finicky. Epoch time must be formatted to include milliseconds and iso time (as string like above) *must* contain microseconds.

Comment: Additionally, if you write the timestamp like "2015-10-18T00:00:00Z00:00" then mongoexport will complain about extra text: 00:00.

Comment: On Mac I could not get this to work. I had to use: `mongoexport   -d myDb -c myCollection  -q '{ "timestamp" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2015-11-01T12:57:00.000Z" }}}'`   *Note*: the double quotes *had to be* inside the string, with single quotes outside.

Comment: This is not a valid answer for mongo 3.x.

Answer (score 9):

I used @wdberkeley's answer as a starting point but that particular date string did not work for me. I had to use a 'T' to separate the date and the time:

```
mongoexport --username user --password pass --host host --db dbName --collection coll --type=csv --query '{"_created_at": { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2017-12-21T12:57:00.506Z" } }}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Had to use a different syntax in windows.

```
mongoexport --host 192.168.1.5 --db dbname --collection files --query "{ "ModifyDate" : { "$lte" : { "$date" : '2019-02-17T00:00:00.000Z' } }}"
```

Difference being the single quotes around the date.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with mongo 2.4, you need to use $date with
 "a 64-bit signed integer for milliseconds" (https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.4/reference/mongodb-extended-json/)
in your case:

```
mongoexport.exe -h *MYHOST* -p *MYPORT* -q "{'time':{'$gte':{"$date": 1419166620506},'$lt': {"$date": 1419166740506}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for Late 2021 for Windows:

Consider **Git Bash** to run it, as I was not able to make it work in Windows Terminal

`mongoexport --hostname=$MYHOST --password=$MYPWD --query='{"time":{"$gte":{"$date":"2014-12-21 12:57:00.506Z"},"$lt":{"$date":"2014-12-21 12:59:00.506Z"}}}' mongodb://IP --out=myoutfile.json`

Answer (score 0):

I have mongoexport version 3.6.1 on Windows. I have to use **Git Bash** as Fabien Haddadi but in my case works with date in milliseconds

```
-query '{ "Time": { "$gte": new Date(1609455600000)} }'
```