# Use mongoexport with a --query for ISODate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongoexport

I have this query but i´m getting a syntax error: unexpected identifier

```
mongoexport --db ium --collection events \
  --query 'db.events.find({'created_at' : {
      $gte: ISODate("2016-03-01T00:00:00.001Z"),
      $lte: ISODate("2016-03-29T23:59:59:59.000Z")
    }, 
    "name" : "UPDATE_SUCCESS"})' \
 --out guille1_test.json
```

what can it be wrong?

Comment: try using "created_at"

Comment: @jmugz3 There was a bit more wrong than the misuse of "quoting" inside the argument string, as there are clear usage errors to correct as well as something not commonly understood about querying with "dates".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to use ["extended json"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) in queries with mongoexport. So the way to specify "dates" is with [`$date`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#date) instead. And the [`--query`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption--query) is just the "query string" in JSON format. Not the whole command entered into the shell:

```js
mongoexport --db ium --collection events \
  --query '{ 
    "created_at": { 
      "$gte": { "$date": "2016-03-01T00:00:00.001Z" },
      "$lte": { "$date": "2016-03-29T23:59:59.000Z" }
    },
    "name": "UPDATE_SUCCESS"
  }' \
  --out guile1_test.json
```

Note also the corrected date string in the [`$lte`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/) argument and of course the "quoting" use of `''` around the body of the JSON argument and `""` around the internal expressions and values. It s **important** that these types of quotes are different, as well as "shell arguments" should have their "outer" quotes as `''`, otherwise the "shell" tries to evaluate the expression contained.

Comment: Thank you man, in just a beginner here with mongodb as you can see hehe. Anyway this format also is bringing unexpected error. Perfhaps changing the date format to UNIX epoch?



mongoexport --db ium --collection events --query ' {"created_at" : { $gte: {  "$date": 2016-03-01T00:00:00.001Z"} },  "name" : "UPDATE_SUCCESS"}' --out guille_test.json

Comment: @Guillermo-Casco The error is because you are still missing quotes around the value to `"$date"`. Here `2016-03-01T00:00:00.001Z"` see the missing `"` before the date. All you need to do is copy/paste what is provided in the answer, since that is the direct translation of what you attempted in your question, but without any format errors in the formed JSON.

Comment: Is there a way to use a variable in the argument given to the $date section (e.g., varDate="2016-03-01T00:00:00.001Z")?

Comment: The command works but the output of the file has
`"created_at":{"$date":"2021-07-28T00:01:00.766Z"}`
How can it be saved in the json format?

Answer (score 3):

Another working solution is by using the `new Date()` constructor as described in the [MongoDB manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/).  This will result in a smaller query body footprint like so:

```
    mongoexport --db ium --collection events \
  --query '{ 
    "created_at": { 
      "$gte": new Date("2016-03-01T00:00:00.001Z"),
      "$lte": new Date("2016-03-29T23:59:59.000Z")
    },
    "name": "UPDATE_SUCCESS"
  }' \
  --out guile1_test.json
```

This approach worked for me out-of-the-box while all other alternatives failed.  There is a relative article describing this approach [here](https://coderwall.com/p/ejxgjg/mongoexport-query-with-using-date).

Comment: With `mongoexport` r4.2.3, I get "Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: invalid JSON literal. Position: XX, literal: new". The accepted answer, with `"$gte": { "$date": "..." }`, does work.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to achieve it as following. Because  new Date and IOSDate would be invalid literal for this command.

> For remote host

```
mongoexport --host {{host}} --username {{username}} --password {{passord}} --authenticationDatabase admin --db {{Database}} --collection {{collection Name}} --query '{ "date" : { "$gt" : {"$date":"2019-10-31T00:00:00.000Z"}  } }'  --type json --out {{path of directory where you would want to export file.}}
```

> For local host

```
 mongoexport  --db {{Database}} --collection {{collection Name}} --query '{ "date" : { "$gt" : {"$date":"2019-10-31T00:00:00.000Z"}  } }'  --type json --out {{path of directory where you would want to export file.}}
```

Comment: For local host example: FailedToParse: Date expecting integer milliseconds