# Keep on getting an error on the json format of my mongoexport

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

That's the query that i'm executing:

```
mongoexport --db solutions --collection solution3 --query "{ 'metrictimestamp': { '$gte': { '$date': '2016-03-01T00:00:00.001Z' },'$lte': { '$date': '2016-03-29T23:59:59.000Z' }}}"--out a.json
```

but i keep on getting this error:

**Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: invalid JSON input**

I've tried to invert the quotes, and all the solutions that i saw on [Use mongoexport with a --query for ISODate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36319052/use-mongoexport-with-a-query-for-isodate)

Comment: Is it because there are no space after " before - -

Comment: mongoexport -d solutions -c solution3 -q "{ 'metrictimestamp' : { '$gte': new Date('2018-01-10T00:00:00.001Z'), '$lte': new Date('2018-01-10T00:00:00.001Z')}}" --out a.json

Comment: is that what you said?

Comment: yes same error.

Comment: Please post a sample document you are trying to export.

Comment: {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ea79b5da8d460059a5f58eb"),
        "direction" : 0,
        "metrictimestamp" : ISODate("2018-02-01T02:59:55Z"),
        "odometer" : 19030291,
        "routecode" : 0,
        "speed" : 0,
        "deviceid" : 8155064,
        "vehicleid" : 34489,
        "location" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [
                        -3.878595,
                        -38.533493
                ]
        }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of trial and run, I found it works perfect by passing query through a file instead of command line.

create a file query.json and put your query in normal json format, with double quotes.

```
{"metrictimestamp":{"$gte":{"$date":"2016-03-01T00:00:00.001Z"},"$lte":{"$date":"2016-03-29T23:59:59.000Z"}}}
```

and then run the command passing the file to --queryfile instead of --query

```
mongoexport --db solutions --collection solution3 --queryfile query.json --out a.json
```